# Accessing SMS Message Type Constants

Tags: java, android, constants

Message type constants are defined in [Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html#MESSAGE_TYPE_ALL).

In a nutshell, as provided on other SO answers:

```
MESSAGE_TYPE_ALL    = 0;
MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX  = 1;
MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT   = 2;
MESSAGE_TYPE_DRAFT  = 3;
MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX = 4;
MESSAGE_TYPE_FAILED = 5; // for failed outgoing messages
MESSAGE_TYPE_QUEUED = 6; // for messages to send later
```

I can easily redefine these in my Class, but that doesn't seem efficient given that they are already defined in the Android API. Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns is an interface so I can't just access the constants directly (ie: `Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.MESSAGE_TYPE_OUTBOX` doesn't work).

How can I use these constants? I don't want to redefine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I use these constants?

Use a class that implements the interface (e.g., `Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT`).

Comment: Hmm it turns out the reason I can't access that is because I'm targeting API Level 16, that interface is not implemented. Do you happen to know how to access those constants on that API? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @Juicy: "Do you happen to know how to access those constants on that API?" -- you can't, as they do not exist in that version of the Android SDK. You need to build against API Level 19+ (`compileSdkVersion` in Android Studio, Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse). Note that changing your `compileSdkVersion` does not impact what versions of Android that you support -- it just changes what classes, methods, constants, etc. are available to you at compile time.